# Using python interpreter using ssh connection on Slum cluster server using Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, ssh, pycharm, slurm, pythoninterpreter

I want to use the ssh interpreter of pycharm IDE here is the problems that I have.

I successfully connected to the cluster.

I used SSHF and mount my files on the server to my local machine. 
Now after defining the project on pycharm and using the ssh interpreter, it doesn't work.

Specially, the issue is that when I am pressing the run bottom on my pycharm IDE, it will connect to the directory of the python interpreter using my ssh setting. But I want after connecting to the cluster allocate a compute node and then load the tensorflow module using command "module load tensorflow" and then run the code on ssh.

Is there any way? even I am open to other solution.

What I do currently, I do every of this step manually and only using PyCharm as a text editor with a terminal at the bottom.